# PhpStorm merge branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge, phpstorm

My workflow is as follows. I work on a development branch, push my changes to that branch, and then go on GitHub itself and do a pull request on the Master branch to merge the changes I made on the development branch

I try to do the same thing in PhpStorm. So I push my changes on the development branch, checkout the local Master branch and then merge with the development branch. But all those changes are still only local, so I have to do something stupid like adding an extra space in a file, and then push all the changes to finally see my commits on the remote Master branch

I feel like I'm doing something wrong, could you point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it’s correct. There are two ways for you to merge development branch to master branch: one is **merge to master branch locally and then pushed to remote**, the other is push all branches to remote (such as github) and then **create a pull request** to propose development merge into master.

The difference between the two ways it that if the merge need to notice your co-workers.

**If development is the branch you created locally and it has no effect for others**, then you can merge it locally and then push to remote. And don’t worry for that you adding extra space, it’s actually not. Because for pull request, it will also create a new commit id (the new commit G in the graph).

```
         A-----B     development
        /         
   C---D---E---F     master
```

**After merge**

```
         A-----B      development
        /        \    
   C---D---E---F---G  master
```

**If the development branch is also used for others,** you should merge development branch into master by creating a pull request, so that others can be noticed and can review the changes.

You can refer [git merge book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) for further reading.